# Using nginx try_files with multiple directory trees

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'd like to have nginx handle requests to a specific directory by checking to see if that path/file exists in several separate directories. For example, if my directory root had the following:

```
images/siteA/foo.jpg
images/siteB/b/bar.jpg
images/siteC/example.jpg
```

I'd like `http://example.com/images/foo.jpg` to return the file `foo.jpg`, `http://example.com/b/bar.jpg` to return the file `bar.jpg` and so fourth.

I've tried the following, but it just gets locked in redirect loops (and I don't want it to redirect, but actually serve the file to that URL):

```
  location /images/ {
    try_files /siteA/images/
              /siteB/images/
              /siteC/images/ =404;

  }
```

I've also tried using capture groups like `location ~/images/(.*)/` and adding `$1` to the end of the URLs. I'm a little confused on the documentation and unsure how to accomplish this with nginx.

Comment: In your question you have `http://example.com/b/bar.jpg`, should that be `http://example.com/images/b/bar.jpg` - otherwise it doesn't match the general pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to use a *regular expression* `location` to capture the part of the URI following `/images/`. Then use `try_files` to test a series of URIs using each site prefix.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
    root /path/to/docroot/images;
    try_files /siteA/$1 /siteB/$1 /siteC/$1 =404;
}
```

You could inherit the value of `root` from the surrounding block, in which case adjust the parameters to `try_files` appropriately.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to the accepted answer you can use a [named location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) (`@my_path` for example) to fallback in an other location, for example :

```
location / {
    root /etc/nginx/static;
    try_files $uri @index;
}

location @index {
    root /srv/http;
    try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html =404;
}
```